styling layout for a react app using react-bootstrap
I am working on my frontend UI. I am using react-bootstrap 0.33.1 which supportsbootstrap v3.3.x.
This is how my UI looks like right now.

But, this is not something that I am expecting. I want to achieve something like this.

this is my jsx file:
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Row, Col, FormControl, Button, Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./ListComponent.css";

function ListComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid>
        <Row className="list-header">
          <Col md={4}>
            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Enter name to search" />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <br />
        <Grid className="list-table">
          <Row className="item-row" style={{backgroundColor:'black', color:'white'}}>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              Name
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              Address
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              Rating
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              Picture
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              Action
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row className="item-row">
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              Cox's Bazar
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              Cox's Bazar
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              5
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
            <Image
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Cox%27s_Bazar_Sunset.JPG/186px-Cox%27s_Bazar_Sunset.JPG"
                rounded
                responsive
              />
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              <div className="action">
                <Button bsStyle="primary">Update</Button>
                <Button bsStyle="danger">Delete</Button>
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row className="item-row">
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              Bandarban
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              Bandarban
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              5
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              <Image
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Cox%27s_Bazar_Sunset.JPG/186px-Cox%27s_Bazar_Sunset.JPG"
                rounded
                responsive
              />
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              <div className="action">
                <Button bsStyle="primary">Update</Button>
                <Button bsStyle="danger">Delete</Button>
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row className="item-row">
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              Sundarban
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              Sundarban
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              5
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
            <Image
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Cox%27s_Bazar_Sunset.JPG/186px-Cox%27s_Bazar_Sunset.JPG"
                rounded
                responsive
              />
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={3}>
              <div className="action">
                <Button bsStyle="primary">Update</Button>
                <Button bsStyle="danger">Delete</Button>
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>
        <br />
        <Button bsStyle="primary">Create New Tourist Place</Button>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ListComponent;

And here is my css file:
.list-header input {
  flex: 2;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
}


.list-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* align-items:center; */
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.action {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item-row {
  /* padding: 1%; */
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px
 solid white;
}

What should I change in order to achieve the desired design? I tried different ways but this is the best I can get to.
